# hibernate delete child from parent need fetch all children of parent?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    ...Getter & Setter
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    ...Getter & Setter
}
```

When remove child from parent, hibernate will query all children of this parent:

```
parent.getChilds().remove(child);
```

I have 100000+ child link to the parent. query all children is very slow and unacceptable.

How to fix this question or use other way?

Comment: Plural form of `child` is `children` ;)

Comment: @Antoniossss shame to me.. I really hope you can understand what I mean :)

Comment: OFC i do :) preparing answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate has to fetch all the children in order to prepare proper SQL - needs to know IDs of children elements to delete.
So there is no way to do it using ORM in way you would like to use it, but if you ask yourself a question, how would you do this in plain SQL obvious solution would be

`DELETE c FROM child c  WHERE c.parent_id=parentId`

Hibernate is able to generate such query, but it is done via HPQL. So if you have delcared bidirectional relationship between parent and child and you have `child` has `parent` property, then you could do the following using HPQL:

```
Query q=session.createQuery(`DELETE c FROM chilc WHERE c.parent=:parent`);
q.setObject("parent",parent);
q.execute(); // q.executeUpdate?
```

This way you wil delete all the children of parent without fetching them.

DISCLAIMER: 
Given query may not be 100% accurate because i dont remember Hibernate's `Session API` anymore, but the overall glance on the solution is given and 100% valid. Just reffer to Hiberrnate's docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sessions's `delete` method without using the Parent and cascading the update:

```
sesionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(child);
```

**Update**

It is a good practice to perform merge before a delete like this to make sure its managed:

```
sesionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(child);
```

Comment: This does not makes sens, as you have to fetch children anyway - OP wants to ommit that :)

Comment: Probably i should have asked about more details, but from the question it is not clear from where the `child` comes from. It may be passed as a parameter (as detached entity or still managed) to this method and then you do not need to use parent in order to remove it